# Cmake and Qt5 linking error

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I'm trying to build a Qt5 project with Cmake in order to add some new librairies. The cmake goes well but I have a linking issue when building :

```
Linking CXX executable bin/qGo
CMakeFiles/qGo.dir/src/main.cpp.o: dans la fonction « main »:
main.cpp:(.text+0x102b): undefined reference to « qInitResources_application() »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/qGo] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qGo.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project (qGo)

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake/)

# Répertoire d'installation de Qt5 (dépend de l'installation)
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/Qt/5.4/gcc/")

find_package (OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package (aruco REQUIRED)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# Use moc files in the bin folder
SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

# Find the Qt5 components
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
find_package(Qt5Network)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH bin)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")

include_directories(src)
include_directories(src/audio)
include_directories(src/board)
include_directories(src/game_interfaces)
include_directories(src/game_tree)
include_directories(src/gtp)
include_directories(src/network)
include_directories(src/resources)
include_directories(src/sgf)
include_directories(src/translations)

file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        source_files
        src/*
)

file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        ui_files
        src/*.ui
)

file(
        GLOB_RECURSE
        header_files
        src/*.h
        src/*.hpp
)

QT5_WRAP_UI(header_ui ${ui_files})

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(qGo ${source_files} ${header_ui})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(qGo Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Network Qt5::Multimedia ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${aruco_LIBS})
```

I have also tried to add libraries with ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES} or ${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS} but it did the same.

I've also tried to compile with QtCreator and it works so the problem is with cmake.

Comment: Maybe you also need to link Qt5::Gui. And enable [automoc](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTOMOC.html) in CMake. Another thing that happens on some IDEs (Xcode for example) is: If you add the Q_OBJECT macro somewhere, you have to run CMake manually to generate the correspondig .moc file before compilation.

Comment: automoc is enabled in my CMakeLists.txt no ?
I've tried to add some other modules (like Gui) but it did the same. 
For compiling, I've created an empty folder so it's a "fresh" compilation.

Comment: I just read about the same linker error [here](http://opticks-devs.2021163.n4.nabble.com/Link-error-td4427966.html) and it looks like it's an RCC issue (Qt resource file generation). You can enable [autorcc](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/AUTORCC.html) just like automoc. Maybe that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to append moc and resources to your executable use `qt5_wrap_cpp()` for mocs use `qt5_add_resources()` for resources.

Then you must append vars to `add_executable` check out [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html).

Comment: That solved my problem : I've missed to add _.qrc_ files with `qt5_add_resources()`. 
But `qt5_wrap_cpp()` wasn't necessary thanks to `automoc`.